# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid static id not identifiable by JS

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Grid with static ID:  P1_EMP_DETAILS
I have used this static id at places for css/JS changes and it was working fine.

Due to a requirement I had to use same IG in a JS code. It is used at the on-click submit button's Dynamic action as Execute JS Code.

The code is as follows:

```
var i,records,record, $EMPID, model, $EMPNAME, $EMPSTATUS
view = apex.region("P1_EMP_DETAILS").widget().interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");
if (view.supports.edit)
{
    model = view.model;
    records = view.getSelectedRecords();
    if (records.length > 0)
    {
        for (i=0; i< records.length ; i++)
        {
            record = records [i];
            $EMPID = model.getValue(record , "EMPID");
            $EMPNAME = model.getValue(record , "EMPNAME");
            $EMPSTATUS = model.getValue(record , "EMPSTATUS");
            apex.server.process ("my_ajax_process",
            {x01:$EMPID,
            x02:$EMPNAME,
            x03:$EMPSTATUS
            },
            {type: 'GET', datatype: 'text', success: function (text)
            {
                apex.message.showPageSuccess("Success");
            }}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In the code when i hover over P1_EMP_DETAILS it says invalid item. WHen i submit the IG on front-end i get invalid token error. ("Unexpected token P: Process my.." is not valid JSON")

Is it due to the static id being used?

Comment: Typically, the notation Px_NAME is the naming convention for page items, where x is the page number. A static id is an html attribute, so I follow the naming conventions for html ids (google html id naming convention). In all my code, static ids are lower case with hyphens to separate words (eg emp-details). I'd definitely not mix static ids and page items, the 2 are very different. Cannot tell you if that is the reason of your issue though.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of IG report's static ID property.